# Auto completion in Atom messed up

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, atom-editor

I don't know whether this is specific to javascript or not, but I'm seeing this behavior:

```
console.lo
```

<kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
console.console.log();
```

I would expect it to auto-complete to:

```
console.log();
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think it's better yo post something here: https://discuss.atom.io/ This isn't the right place for that.

Comment: @Michelem removed my last comment, I've cross-posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atom auto-completion works like this:

`log` -> `console.log();`

so it gets confused and auto-completes `console.lo` -> `console.console.log();`

A workaround is using `log` as your short-hand instead.